# Are there better ways to transform my dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a log-file with 130000 lines. Each line contains a CaseID, a timestamp and a code/factor for the activity. The dataframe is ordered on CaseID an timestamp. I need to reorder the data in such a way that I get all the activitycodes belonging to one case on one line, together with the CaseID

Example:

```
df <- data.frame("CaseID" = c(1,1,3,2,1,4,2,3), 
  Activ = as.factor(c("A","B","A","C","D","C", "D", "C")))

  CaseID Activ
1      1     A
2      1     B
3      3     A
4      2     C
5      1     D
6      4     C
7      2     D
8      3     C
```

should be transformed to:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    4
[2,]    3    4   NA
[3,]    1    3   NA
[4,]    3   NA   NA
```

After mutating the dataframe:

```
df %>% arrange(CaseID) %>% mutate(case_rank = cumsum(c(0,as.numeric(diff(as.numeric(CaseID)))!=0)) +1) %>%       group_by(CaseID) %>% mutate(rank = 1:n()) %>% mutate(act_count = n()) -> df
```

I implemented 2 different ways.

```
ptm <- proc.time()
Interim <- matrix(nrow = max(df$case_rank), ncol = max(df$rank))
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  Interim[df[[i, "case_rank"]], df[[i, "rank"]]]  <- as.numeric(df[i, "Activ"])
} 
Interim
print(proc.time() - ptm)

ptm <- proc.time()
cols <- max(df$act_count)
emptyrow <- rep(NA, cols)
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = max(df$case_rank), ncol = cols))
for(row in 1:max(df$case_rank)) 
  df2[row,] <- head(append(as.numeric(filter(df, CaseID == row)$Activ), emptyrow), cols)
m1 <- as.matrix(df2)
print(proc.time() - ptm)
```

After applying this code to the original dataframe, I got these results:

```
   user  system elapsed 
  1.334   0.227   1.581 
   user  system elapsed 
  3.182   1.126   4.351
```

My first question is why the second method is so slow?
The second question is if there are better / alternative ways to this?

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option.

```
df$tmp <- match(df$Activ, sort(unique(df$Activ)))

tmp2 <- unstack(df, tmp ~ CaseID)
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp2, `length<-`, max(lengths(tmp2))))
out
#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#1    1    2    4
#2    3    4   NA
#3    1    3   NA
#4    3   NA   NA
```

---

The first step is to convert the letters to numbers using

```
df$tmp <- match(df$Activ, sort(unique(df$Activ)))
```

`df$tmp` looks like

```
df$tmp
# [1] 1 2 1 3 4 3 4 3
```

Now we use `unstack` which returns a list

```
unstack(df, tmp ~ CaseID)
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 4

#$`2`
#[1] 3 4

#$`3`
#[1] 1 3

#$`4`
#[1] 3
```

What you need to do next is to append `NA`s such that every list element if of the same length. The "same length" is given by `max(lengths(tmp))` and the function to append `NA`s is `` `lengths<-` ``.

```
lapply(tmp2, `length<-`, max(lengths(tmp2)))
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2 4

#$`2`
#[1]  3  4 NA

#$`3`
#[1]  1  3 NA

#$`4`
#[1]  3 NA NA
```

All that is left to do is to `rbind` the list elements using `do.call(rbind, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be `dcast` from the efficient `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, grp := .GRP, Activ]
dcast(df, CaseID ~ rowid(CaseID), value.var = 'grp')[, CaseID := NULL][]
#   1  2  3
#1: 1  2  4
#2: 3  4 NA
#3: 1  3 NA
#4: 3 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented both new methods and executed them with the real data. They are very fast but both don't return the expected values:

```
# 1 (Original)
ptm <- proc.time()
Interim <- matrix(nrow = max(evtlog$case_rank), ncol = max(evtlog$rank))
for (i in 1:nrow(evtlog)) {
  Interim[evtlog[[i, "case_rank"]], evtlog[[i, "rank"]]] <- as.numeric(evtlog[i, "color"])
}
print(proc.time() - ptm)
print(Interim[1, 1:10])

# 3
ptm <- proc.time()
setDT(evtlog)[, grp := .GRP, color]
Interim <- dcast(evtlog, CaseID ~ rowid(CaseID), value.var = 'grp')[, CaseID := NULL][]
print(proc.time() - ptm)
print(Interim[1, 1:10])

# 4
ptm <- proc.time()
evtlog$tmp <- match(evtlog$color, sort(unique(evtlog$color)))
tmp2 <- unstack(evtlog, tmp ~ CaseID)
Interim <- do.call(rbind, lapply(tmp2, `length<-`, max(lengths(tmp2))))
print(proc.time() - ptm)
print(Interim[1, 1:10])
```

This gives this output:

```
 user  system elapsed 
0.491   0.000   0.491 
 [1]  1 10 14 37 11  3 14  8  8  8
 user  system elapsed 
0.011   0.000   0.006 
 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1: 1 2 3 4 5 6 3 7 7  7
 user  system elapsed 
0.006   0.000   0.003 
 [  1]  1  9 12 13 10  3 12  7  7  7
```

When I match the results from my implementation against the levels from the evtlog:

```
head(levels(evtlog$color))

[1] "Bestelaanvraag Aanmaken"              "Bestelaanvraag Aanvraaggegevens"      "Bestelaanvraag Afwijzen"             
[4] "Bestelaanvraag Annuleren"             "Bestelaanvraag Document intrekken"    "Bestelaanvraag Geen actie ondernomen"
```

I get the correct answers so the problem should lie in the translation from the factor in the evtlog to the integer.
For the second option (# 4), the solution was simple. Changing

```
match(evtlog$color, sort(unique(evtlog$color)))
```

to

```
match(evtlog$color, levels(evtlog$color))
```

did it.

I haven't found a solution for the first option (# 3) yet.

Thanks,
Ben